# Do not see any running application on sever UI

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to connect to my Spark server thanks to SparklyR locally.
In practice, on my server, I open a R session and execute

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

I get no error message, but when I open the server UI on

> http://my.server.local:8080/

I do not see any Running Application. So I guess there is an issue ?

When I open a SparkR console directly, I'm able to see a Running Application.
I would really like to work with SparklyR, how should I do ?

Comment: Did your try ports 8081, 7077 or 4040 ?

Answer (score 0):

When starting a local server, for example:

```
Fokkos-MacBook-Pro:~ fokkodriesprong$ sparkR

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Launching java with spark-submit command /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/bin/spark-submit   "sparkr-shell" /var/folders/dm/5qvjnrpx4m92318vwt4svfsh0000gn/T//Rtmpgtr1tn/backend_port1227e57d8a425 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/08/21 15:16:09 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/08/21 15:16:13 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException

 Welcome to
    ____              __ 
   / __/__  ___ _____/ /__ 
  _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/ 
 /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version  2.2.0 
    /_/ 


 SparkSession available as 'spark'.
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
>
```

Then the Spark UI should be available at http://localhost:4040/